# Row Division in Scipy Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to divide a sparse matrix's rows by scalars given in an array.

For example, I have a `csr_matrix` `C` :

```
C = [[2,4,6], [5,10,15]]
D = [2,5]
```

I want the result of `C` after division to be :

```
result = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I have tried this using the method that we use for `numpy` arrays:

```
result = C / D[:,None]
```

But this seems really slow. How to do this efficiently in sparse matrices?

Comment: An earlier question on row wise divide, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080315/division-of-sparse-matrix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's a sparse matrix solution using manual replication with `indexing` -

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

r,c = C.nonzero()
rD_sp = csr_matrix(((1.0/D)[r], (r,c)), shape=(C.shape))
out = C.multiply(rD_sp)
```

The output is a sparse matrix as well as opposed to the output from `C / D[:,None]` that creates a full matrix. As such, the proposed approach saves on memory.

Possible performance boost with replication using `np.repeat` instead of indexing -

```
val = np.repeat(1.0/D, C.getnnz(axis=1))
rD_sp = csr_matrix((val, (r,c)), shape=(C.shape))
```

---

**Approach #2**

Another approach could involve `data` method of the sparse matrix that gives us a flattened view into the sparse matrix for `in-place` results and also avoid the use of `nonzero`, like so -

```
val = np.repeat(D, C.getnnz(axis=1))
C.data /= val
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked like a charm! On my dataset my method was taking 60 seconds. And now it is taking 1 second. Thanks.

Comment: @user3787291 How about `Approach #2`?

Comment: yes it worked too. And what if i need to divide column wise ? How do you divide column wise ?

Comment: @user3787291 I got stuck in this problem but had to do it for column wise. There's just one small modification needed. 
**(1.0/D)[r]** changes to **(1.0/D)[c]**

`rD_sp = csr_matrix(((1.0/D)[c], (r,c)), shape=(C.shape))`

Answer (score 0):

Question: I want to divide a sparse matrix's rows by scalars given in an array.
For example:
C = [[2,4,6], [5,10,15]]
D = [2,5]

Answer : use ["multiply"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply) provided by sparse matrix interface - it allows to "pointwise" multiply matrices by matrices as well as by vectors and scalars

> ```
>     C = [[2,4,6], [5,10,15]]
>     D = [2,5]
> ```
>
> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

> c = csr_matrix(C)
> c2 = c.multiply( 1/np.array(D).reshape(2,1) )

> c2.toarray()
>
> 'output:' array([[ 2,  4,  6],
> [ 5, 10, 15]], dtype=int64)

PS

Thanks to Alexander Kirillin

Answer (score -1):

one line code: `result = [[C[i][j]/D[i] for j in range(len(C[0]))] for i in range(len(D))]`

```
C = [[2,4,6], [5,10,15]] #len(C[0]) = 3
D = [2,5] # len(D) = 2
result = [[C[i][j]/D[i] for j in range(len(C[0]))] for i in range(len(D))]
print result
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this work for csr_matrix as requested.

Answer (score -1):

If you first cast `D` to type `numpy.matrix` (which I'm assuming you can do unless `D` is too big to fit into memory), then you can just run

```
C.multiply(1.0 / D.T)
```

to get what you want.