# Normalize scipy sparse matrix with number of nonzero elements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to divide each row of the csr_matrix by the number of non zero entries in that row.

For example : Consider a csr_matrix A:

```
A = [[6, 0, 0, 4, 0], [3, 18, 0, 9, 0]]
Result = [[3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [1, 6, 0, 3, 0]]
```

What's the shortest and efficient way to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the counts with `getnnz` method and then replicate and divide in-place into its flattened view obtained with `data` method -

```
s = A.getnnz(axis=1)
A.data /= np.repeat(s, s)
```

Inspired by [`Row Division in Scipy Sparse Matrix 's solution post : Approach #2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49254531/).

Sample run -

```
In [15]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

In [16]: A = csr_matrix([[6, 0, 0, 4, 0], [3, 18, 0, 9, 0]])

In [18]: s = A.getnnz(axis=1)
    ...: A.data /= np.repeat(s, s)

In [19]: A.toarray()
Out[19]: 
array([[3, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [1, 6, 0, 3, 0]])
```

Note: To be compatible between Python2 and 3, we might want to use `//` -

```
A.data //=  ...
```

Comment: I ran into an error because `A` is of type `int64` and the `A.data /= np.repeat(s, s)` tries to casting `A`.

Comment: @Tai Are you on Python3?

Comment: Yes, on Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Divakar gives an in-place method. My trial creates a new array.

```
from scipy import sparse
A = sparse.csr_matrix([[6, 0, 0, 4, 0], [3, 18, 0, 9, 0]])
A.multiply(1.0/(A != 0).sum(axis=1))
```

We multiply the inverse values of the sum of non-zero parts in each row. Note that one may want to make sure there is no dividing-by-zero errors.

As Divakar pointed out: `1.0`, instead of `1`, is needed at `A.multiply(1.0/...)` to be compatible with Python 2.

Comment: For Python2, the results might be all zeros. So, I guess we need `1.0` division there.

Comment: @Divakar got you!